# Differentiate between 2 checkboxes in this code snippet in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I have a table that has a checkbox. I configured a function to do some function on click of the checkbox as follows:

> $("#table").on('click', ":checkbox", function() {   ….    });

Now I need to add another checkbox in the table. How can I add to this code snippet the name of the checkbox so that I can differentiate between the 2?
Please note that it is a checkbox per row and will be 2 checkboxes per row. So I can not use an id. Only `name` or `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [attribute-equals-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("#table").on('click', ":checkbox[name=meh]", function() { ... });
```

Or by using class names:

```
$("#table").on('click', ":checkbox.meh", function() { ... });
```

---

PS: I would suggest replacing `:checkbox` with `input[type=checkbox]` for performance:

> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.

Comment: Same applies for `input[type="checkbox"]`? Will be `input[type="checkbox"][name=meh]`?

Comment: Yuppppppppppppppppppppppppp!